# Writing a Test Class for an Extension

Tags: unit-test, controller-extension

How would I write a test class for this extension?

```
public class PictureofSuccess{

public Account ac {get;set;}
public  List <Picture_of_Success__c> pictures {get;set;}
public Boolean noImage {get;set;}
public Boolean test {get;set;}

public PictureofSuccess(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    this.ac = [Select Id, Key_Account_Number__c From Account Where Id = :stdController.getId()];
    pictures = [Select Picture_of_Success__c From Picture_of_Success__c Where Active_POS__c = True AND Key_Account_Number__c = :ac.Key_Account_Number__c];


    if (!pictures.isEmpty()){
        noImage = False;
   } else{
       noImage = True;
   }

 }

}
```

I keep getting the error Constructor not defined: [PictureofSuccess].() when I try and write a test class. Thanks

Comment: Can you show the test code that you have written that is giving you that error

Comment: Thats because you are calling the no-parameter constructor from test class when you have not defined any no-parameter constructor in the class.

Answer (score 3):

here's your issue

The controller class  `PictureOfSuccess` does not have a constructor defined with a null argument; instead, you have to pass it an argument of type `ApexPages.StandardController`.

For example, your testmethod will need:

```
Account a = new Account(name='foo');
insert a;
ApexPages.StandardController ctlr = new ApexPages.StandardController(a);
PictureofSuccess ext    = new PictureofSuccess(ctlr);
```

You may have been confused by [this page in the Visualforce Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm?SearchType=Stem) - where the example tests a custom controller..

Comment: this is if the controller is an extension of a standar controller, what if it is an extension of a custom controller?

Comment: there is no concept of an extension to a custom controller, an extension is to a standardController; custom controllers stand on their own (of course they can extend a base(super) class but that is a different sense